# What highest amount of energy can we get from a laser?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, laser, fusion

Can we get high energy from laser like fusion and fission reactions ? what is highest energy we can get from laser ?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Ignition_Facility

Comment: Ummm, a laser has exactly as much energy as you put in, like a light bulb. It is certainly not a source of energy. Perhaps you could clarify what you mean?

Comment: @ChrisWhite i saw many videos on youtube laser can cut something because of Thermal energy i think .. is there another energy can be obtained from laser like thermal energy ? am i clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Researchers at Osaka University are claiming to have fired the most powerful laser in the world. The 2-petawatt (two quadrillion watt) pulse lasted just one picosecond (a trillionth of a second). For a rough comparison, in 2013, a 50 kilowatt (50,000 watt) laser shot down a drone two kilometers away.Jul 28, 2015

[image]

[image]